# Having problem in configuring nginx to open wordpress on my subdomain

Tags: wordpress, nginx, digital-ocean

So i have 2 subdomains which are directing to websites build on 2 different platforms.

**The main Domain name is pointed towards : static HTML page.
1.) ex1.main-site.com : opens a angular app.
2.)ex2.main-site.com : opens a wordpress app.**

The angular app and html pages are opening properly However
the problem is whenever i try to open the ex2.main-site.com (wordpress website) it redirects to main-site.com automatically and doesn't open the wordpress website at all.

Also if i open it as main-site.com/ex2 under a different path the wordpress website works properly.
I have tried different solutions but not able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

The following is the nginx code:

```
server{
  index index.php;
  server_name ex2.main-site.com;
  root /var/www/main-site/ex2;

  location / {
    root /var/www/main-site/ex2;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?is_args$args;
  }

 location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured Wordpress with the correct SITEURL and HOME? You can change it in general settings or one of the configuration files. See [Changing The Site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)

Comment: Yes i have already done the wordpress configurations.